# Change arrow color for popover created from storyboard in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, popover

I'm trying to change the default popover arrow color for a popover defined as a storyboard segue (not built programmatically) from a button. The following picture shows the white default popover arrow:

[image]

When I add

```
navigationController?.popoverPresentationController?.backgroundColor = myNavBarColor
```

to the `viewWillAppear` method of the `UIViewController` presented in the popover, the result is the following:

[image]

Defining a new `UIPopoverBackgroundView` class for the `UIPopoverPresentationController` during the `prepareForSegue` method of the main `UIViewController` is "too late".

I hope there'll be a simple fix (with the same storyboard segue as popover) for such a common issue.

Comment: Set the background color in `prepareForSegue`. Like this `segue.destinationViewController.popoverPresentationController.backgroundColor`.

Comment: It works for me, thank you very much! ;)

Comment: Note that I first had to set `segue.destination.modalPresentationStyle = .popover`, otherwise `segue.destination.popoverPresentationController` would be `nil`. Apart from that, the solutions works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Set the background color of the popoverPresentationController of your viewController :

```
let viewController = YOUR_VIEW_CONTROLLER
viewController.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
if let presentation = viewController.popoverPresentationController {
    presentation.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
}
present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also set it inside the view that will be housed inside the popoverPresentationController

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    popoverPresentationController?.backgroundColor = view.backgroundColor
}
```